# Setting up Java Eclipse IDE for Raspberry-pi

Tags: java, eclipse, raspberry-pi

I have installed java and eclipse in my raspberry-pi.

[image]

Installed eclipse using

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Eclipse is installed and i am able to open the IDE through VNC.But there is no run configurations set in eclipse.It is asking for new run configurations.

[image]

Even in the run configuration there is no JRE option.

[image]

I also want to add external jar files.Searched the web but didn't get much for eclipse configuration on raspberry-pi

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the absolute minimum version of Eclipse installed which does not have the Java Development Tools installed.

You should be able to install this in `Help > Install New Software`, work with the main Eclipse site and install `Eclipse Java Development Tools` (under Programming Languages).